# Data doesn't appear in table created with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Have some troubles with directives in AngularJS.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<table>
    <thead>
    .......
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    .......
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="values in Items.rows">
            <td ng-repeat="data in values">{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Controller for my element:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
Application.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

// Some logic
$scope.Items = {

     head: ["id", "Name", "Age"],

     rows: [
             ["1", "Bob", "23"],
             ["2", "Sam", "23"],
             ["3", "Joe", "23"]
           ]
     };
           // Some other logic
    }
}
```

And finally directive:

```
Application.directive('Table', function() {
  return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace: true,
           scope: {},
           templateUrl: 'Table.html'
         }
});
```

The problem is in HTML page rendering. When I try to show the page my data doesn't appear in a table... Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Make a fiddle out of it and post the link here .

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the rows array, as Items is an object:

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="values in Items.rows">
            <td ng-repeat="data in values">{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

What  is the directive supposed to do? If you are trying to do what i think you are you don't need it.

Also you repeat over items but i think you need items.rows:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<table>
    <thead>
    .......
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    .......
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="values in Items.rows">
            <td ng-repeat="data in values">{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It was just typing mistake. Already fixed. Doesn't work. I'm doing a universal table. This table I will reuse in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If what your directive only does, is replacing particular tag with Table.html then I think you should use `ng-include`, for example in that way:

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-include="'Table.html'">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Table.html:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
    .......
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    .......
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="values in Items.rows">
            <td ng-repeat="data in values">{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But, if you really want a directive (and by that I mean "if you want to use link/compile function and do something more than just loading template"), you should be aware of how scopes work with directives. First, `scope: {}` will create a new isolate scope for directive, which is empty (so `Items` variable is not visible). You can get rid of isolate scope (by leaving `scope` unset) or, what I think is a better solution, write:

```
scope: {
    items: '&'
}
```

It will create a new isolate scope for this directive but in this scope there will be `items` variable which will be set to whatever you assign to `items` attribute on `table` element.

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <generic-table items="Items"></generic-table>
</div>
```

**Table.html:** the same as previous.

Notice, that you should also change name of your directive to `genericTable` or whatever you want, because in old scenario `table` is a directive - imagine a directive including itself, it's not a good idea, I suppose.